# Ruby require files in relative folders

Tags: ruby, sinatra, require

I'm having an issue in Ruby 1.9.3.
This is my File structure

```
App
 |-- config
   |-- database_setup.rb
 |-- models
   |-- *.rb
```

My database_setup.rb needs to require all of the rb files from the models folder. I'm having a hard time getting it to find the correct directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

Have you tried:

```
Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..',  'models', '**/*.rb')].sort.each do |file|
  require file
end
```